# Creating realistic small flames artifacts

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I would like to reproduce this kind of artifacts on a flame simulation (see picture)
I am able to come up with some nice flame simulations but I haven't found a way to reproduce the little waves of fire that propagate at the surface of the emitter.

Any idea where to start from ?

[image]